# Git Authentication failed error on server but not on local

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I have git repository and it was working fine till two days back. Now I am getting an error as **"remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/repo/'"** on EC2 instance. I am using personal access token for authentication with the same personal token I am able to push or pull from my local machine.

I tried command for setting remote url as `git remote set-url origin  https://github.com/repo` but did not help

Comment: Go to credential manager, delete the credentials, pull again, it will ask for username/password again, then you are good to go.

Comment: Which credential manager, Github?

Comment: Windows Credential Manager

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS and issue is occurring on ec2 instance server

Comment: Did you change your password recently? You can also do git config -l to verify all the git configurations like username.

Comment: @ArpitJain I did not change password, neither I nor my team members able to pull as they are getting same error

Comment: Try to run `git pull origin master` and it would ask for your username and password(Enter Personal access token) and would save it to the cache.

Comment: @ArpitJain I tried running above command as well but getting same error.

Comment: @NageshKatke, may be try cloning the repo again?

Comment: @ArpitJain Surely will check.

Answer (score 0):

Look like it has something to do with the credentials instead of the URL of the repo.
Check that if you are using personal access token it has not expired.
If you are using username and password you may want to try to re-enter your credentials depending on how you set them up (like Credential Storage).
If you are using the credential helper store:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

You credentials should be stored in plain text at root of your home folder:

```
~/.git-credentials
```